# Как получить неизвестные файлы в директории?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как переименовать сразу несколько файлов из выбранной директории, если имена файлов заранее не известны?

Comment: что значит неизвестные? по какому признаку вы их хотите переименовывать?

Comment: Ну может возникнуть такая необходимость, например, если имя файла содержит китайские символы...

Comment: ну так что мешает тогда пройтись обычным циклам по файлам директории и переименовать не устроившие вас файлы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имена файлов заданы на Memo1, во что переименовывать на Memo2, то простой обход в цикле:

```
for i:=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
begin
  RenameFile(Memo1.Lines[i],Memo2.Lines[i]);
end;
```

Comment: При чем здесь memo? Имена файлов неизвестны, значит надо как минимум получить хэндл каждого файла, и потом уже его имя!

Comment: Asen, вы правильно меня поняли. То как предложил agdk26 не прокатит.